# Jupyter notebook can not been started because of output cells

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I kinda shot my leg:

By accident, collected so much output in jupyter cell, that it crashed. When i tried to restart it - found out that browser just can't load it. No errors - just can not load( doesn't show cells, can't start the kernel )

So, how can i access the code? :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From terminal or CommandLine you can convert `.ipynb` to `.py`

```
ipython nbconvert --to python <YourNotebookName>.ipynb
```